# Android Firebase: onChildAdded called with only delta after setValue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my chat app, when a msg notification is received in the FcmService, a deliveryReceipt is set for that msgId.

This is how I am updating a specific field of the message object when a notification for that message is received.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages/groups")
            .child(groupId)
            .child("-L7VySOmgmcePMVokcVj") //messageId
            .child("deliveryReceipts")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
            .setValue(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This successfully updates the message with the new field "**deliveryReceipts**":

[image]

Now when I open the chat itself, to sync all chat messages, the last iteration of `onChildAdded()` is triggered with just the field I explicitly updated previously, i.e. "**deliveryReceipts**".

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages/groups")
            .child(groupId)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    final ChatData chatData = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatData.class);
                    if (chatData != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: " + dataSnapshot);
                    }
                }
```

This is how the Firebase filtered logs look like:

> CHILD_ADDED: { -L7W43o02tkhToxee5dQ: {deliveryReceipts={KS3lGdZkByQI3QTASUuhozfTUB12=1520973407769}, serverTimestamp=1520973403735, authorUid=BjqACatBjUSm2kFeEEeUjL7NsCC3, createdTimestamp=1520973403883, lubbCount=0, message=H ICICI} }
>
> CHILD_ADDED: { -L7W8HtvWnRix1WMpB0Z:
>   {deliveryReceipts={KS3lGdZkByQI3QTASUuhozfTUB12=1520974512436}} }

The last message only has "**deliveryReceipts**" which is the new field the client had set for that message, missing old fields like `authorUid`, `createdTimestamp`, etc.

As you can see in the logs. the previous messages returned in `onChildAdded()` are fine. Only the last, recently updated message is broken.

I cannot figure out why onChildAdded is called with just the field I had updated earlier, without all the other fields.

**UPDATE:** Here's the captured Datasnapshot from `onChildAdded`

```
DataSnapshot { key = -L7iEsm4WqF20CbSuAhP, value = {deliveryReceipts={KS3lGdZkByQI3QTASUuhozfTUB12=1521194344681}} }
```

**UPDATE 2** Here is the log when dataSnapshot itself is printed as in the above updated code for `onChildAdded()`

```
D/ChatFragment: onChildAdded: DataSnapshot { key = -L7nmHBXJsLG-PFTF5wm, value = {deliveryReceipts={KS3lGdZkByQI3QTASUuhozfTUB12=1521287243021}} }
```

**UPDATE 3**: Replicated scenario on a test project. Here's the Github repo: https://github.com/ishaangarg/FireWrite

How to replicate: steps outlined in the repo

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with only hard-coded values? E.g. we can't really know what `getMessagesRef().child(notifData.getGroupId()).child(notifData.getMessageId())` points to. If you just use hard-coded values and make sure they match your data structure, it'll be easier to correlate the code, the data, and the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question.

Comment: Where does the logging you show come from? It doesn't seem to match the `Log.d` statement in the code you provided: `Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());`.

Comment: Ya these are firebase logs, seen when you select the "Firebase" filter in logcat.

Comment: It looks more like wire traffic, which is not necessarily what you get in your code. Please check what data your `dataSnapshot` contains in `onChildAdded`.

Comment: Updated ques with the dataSnapshot. I'm updating the deliveryReceipt from `FirebaseMessagingService` if that helps...

Comment: Please show the exact code that you use to print the output, because right now you're only logging `dataSnapshot.getKey()`. The reason I'm suspicious btw is that I've never seen a Firebase client with partial data, so I suspect the problem is elsewhere. E.g. the snapshot you see matches the literal write that you do, so I'd expect to see that data when there was nothing else at the path you write to.

Comment: Updated code to print logcat. Thanks for helping out, it's really confusing for our team.

Comment: While working on reproducing this, I realized: if there was already data in the child, changing it would fire `onChildChanged`. Since you're seeing `onChildAdded`, the client thinks it's a new child. As said: I've never seen it do that when the child wasn't actually new. I'll continue to try and reproduce, but could really use an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at this point.

Comment: I've replicated the crash on a test project, lemme upload it to github...

Comment: question updated with github repo & steps to replicate are included in the repo itself. Thanks :)